# ChunkLoadError for lazy load module when serving through Laravel server

Tags: angular, angular11

I am working on integrating Angular (version 11) with Laravel. For this I had copied all the files within the /dist folder to public folder of Laravel and include them in the welcome view blade file. Somehow Angular started working but an issue occurs for lazy loading routes.

[Check in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCFx.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCFx.png):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCFx.png]

Please suggest any solution for the same.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
It has resolved now. Issue was that some of the chunk files  were unable to locate because of incorrect url. So, I corrected deployUrl in angular.json file.
This works for me..
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo45K.png

Files path in welcome.blade.php
[enter image description here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLcdr.png

When you run "ng build --prod" command for your project. Then Angular will create "/src/build/dist" folder containing compiled css and js files of the entire project which you can easily deploy on any server by simply adding them in the entry point of application.

So,firstly I copied the "build/dist" folder in laravel public directory i.e. "public/build/dist". 
Secondly, copy the css,js files(let'say these are core files) enclosed in <script> and <style> tag from src/build/dist/index.html of Angular to the entry point of laravel like welcome.balde.php. 

/dist folder contains more files other than core files.
These are those complied files which contain the data related to your other modules. Like I have created admin module and many others. 

As these core files(css and js files of src/build/dist/index.html) need and include other pending css and js files of the dist folder to run application. 
In my scenario for core files, I gave url of laravel public/build/dist/ as follows:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/dist/styles.a17557ece6ba34c7b644.css">
<script src="build/dist/runtime.d7b70900f051ed525c88.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="build/dist/polyfills.190dcc723c6b07098e8a.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="build/dist/scripts.5eaee51c513cfdd21cef.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="build/dist/main.7d77d7722d89fabe01c0.js" defer=""></script>

But unfortunately then I stuck in this error saying "chunk load error". 
After struggling many days I understand the cause and then I mentioned the deployUrl:"build/dist/" in angular.json which resolved my issue. Here I have configured deployUrl to create "dist" folder within "build" folder.
 
So,just because of these core files we don't have to specify all files present in dist folder in the welcome.blade.php or entry point of application..

Hope it helps :) and please share your view..
```

Comment: It is better that you update the question instead of posting an answer

Comment: Well if anything else you need that should be mentioned in this . Then please share.